# Trouble Bouncing a Session :(

Tags: filesize

I have never had this issue before, but I recorded a session and now it is not letting me bounce it to the desktop or my external (where I normally bounce to).  The error statement it gives me says the requested file size is too large for the file type to support.
I am frustrated and curious as to why this just started happening with this session after almost 2 years of dealing with ProTools 8.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an old format hard drive? FAT32 has limitations on file size.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Panozkp, is it a fat32 volume? If so you are limited to 4 gb minus 1 byte.

Also Wav & aiff files have a 4gb (sometimes 2gb) size limit as well. I think this might be your issue, since it does specify that it's too large for the file type.

What is the sample rate / length / number of channels of your bounce file?

Answer (score 1):

for many reasons i would suggest not bouncing but busing and printing inside the pt session.